# Git branches and commit disappeared

Tags: git

**EDIT: My error!**

After copy-pasting a folder with a Visual Studio project app I found that both original and copied projects are now "reset" to first two commits.

All local commits and branches are gone.

Git prune just returns first two commits.

Is there anything I can do to retrieve those commits? Are they completely gone? Is it possible?

Comment: Moving a folder alone should not do _anything_ to the previous commits.  You must have done something else for this to happen.  In general, you are responsible for knowing the state of your repository at all times.

Comment: from the docs: `git-prune - Prune all unreachable objects from the object database`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - no, I did not do anything else. I copy-pasted the solution, open the copied one, branches were missing, checked the copied from which I copied - everything missing as well. I did not run git commands

Comment: `I did not run git commands` ... then you didn't lose branches or commits.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - you're right, I opened the solution again, this time from the list which appears when you open Visual Studio, not from the File->Open and it worked... Not sure what's going on :/ probably panicking too much